# Docker - "127.0.0.1" is not a valid port - Django

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

Hi I have a django app that I am currently moving to docker and ducker hub to start testing. I currently have the docker file and the project is building. There is an issue that is coming up when trying to run the

```
python manage.py runserver command.
```

It is saying that there is the following issue:

```
omars-mbp:helloworld omarjandali$ docker run omaryap/helloworld
CommandError: "127.0.0.1" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.
```

Here is my docker file for the django project I am currently running. If anyone can help me with this.

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR hello
COPY requirements.txt ./
EXPOSE 8000
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1"]
```

Comment: On which port is your application running? `CMD` should probably be: CMD `["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`..

Comment: Did you even read the error message before pasting it here ?

Comment: I tried that and it still did not work ??? @marcolz

Comment: It is running but when i try to access the container in my web browser, i am getting an error page. I am using `127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: You're a developer, you should know that "I am getting an error page" is useless, what matters is _what the error says_. In fact your question was completely explained by the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Dockerfile you provided I assume that the application is running on port 8000, so it should be:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR hello
COPY requirements.txt ./
EXPOSE 8000
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

What was clearly explained in the message:

> CommandError: "127.0.0.1" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.

Comment: I have the image running but when I go to localhost: `127.0.0.1:8000` there is no webpage displaying I am getting an error page @Opai

Comment: @OmarJandali It might be related to your local settings of the project. Investigate the logs `docker logs -f <cointainerId>`. Are you it's running on 8000 port?

Comment: yeah my docker file looks exactly like the example above in this answer

Comment: @OmarJandali, this is not `Dockerfile` that is important but django settings as well. Have you looked into the logs?

Comment: i ran the commmand above, but nothing is coming up so i cant see any logs

Comment: What did you run? Step by step.

Comment: If i run it just from my local machine by running the command in terminal, it works. When i try to run it from the docker it does not work. Is it because it is not connecting to the local host on my computer....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158935/discussion-between-opal-and-omar-jandali).

Comment: `omars-mbp:helloworld omarjandali$ docker run -d omaryap/helloworld
073890a0db4037a64d5445332204c01cc63b5badd116533ecff1e82a34e626ad
omars-mbp:helloworld omarjandali$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
073890a0db40        omaryap/helloworld   "python manage.py ..."   2 seconds ago       Up 13 seconds       8000/tcp            affectionate_franklin
omars-mbp:helloworld omarjandali$ docker logs -f 073890a0db4037a64d5445332204c01cc63b5badd116533ecff1e82a34e626ad`